# python: how to interpolate a closed contour

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

For example, I have 4 control point, and I know it should be a closed contour.

Firstly, I use the [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx) to interpolate the contour, and the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
t = np.arange(0, 1.25, 0.25)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
tck,u = interpolate.splprep([x,y], s=0)
unew = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
out = interpolate.splev(unew, tck)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', out[0], out[1])
plt.axis([-1.05, 1.05, -1.05, 1.05])
plt.title('Spline of parametrically-defined curve')
plt.show()
```

And the result is:

[image]

In my thought, the four point should be interpolated into a circle. However, the result is kindly differ from a circle. Then, I find [interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) may be a solution. The code is:

```
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y = np.c_[np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)]
cs = interpolate.CubicSpline(theta, y, bc_type='periodic')
# cs = interpolate.CubicSpline(y[:, 0], y[:, 1], bc_type='periodic')
xs = 2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
ys = cs(xs)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.5, 4))
ax.plot(np.cos(xs), np.sin(xs), 'r', label='true')
ax.plot(ys[:, 0], ys[:, 1], label='spline')
ax.axes.set_aspect('equal')
ax.legend(loc='center')
plt.show()
```

And the result is:
[image]

The result is actually what I need. However, in the really application, I don't know the theta, because the real control may be not a circle. In this way, if I only have the control point (n*2), how can we interpolate it into a close contour?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: If you know you want a circle that fits to those 4 points, why don't you just compute its center and radius? Also, if you know it's a circle and you have many points, why don't you fit, rather than interpolate?

Comment: Actually, I just know it should be a closed contour. Thus, I can not calculate the center and radius. But if I give the control point [cos(), sin()], the interpolated contour should be a circle.